# How to query an adjacent previous record to another record you look up in Rails with Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am building a Rails app to pull data from the [Johns Hopkins Covid-19 Github project](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19) and to calculate the daily growth rates for cases and deaths. I started this because I wanted to see the change in the data every day for my city of Nashville. Currently, I have a hard-coded html table, which [you can see here](https://covid615.com), but I'm trying to make it dynamic so that it works for every county in the US.

At this point I'm blocked trying to model the database and calculate the daily growth rates on a `before_save` callback because I'm not sure how to look up the records I need.

**What is a decent way to find a record in rails that is the adjacent previous record to the one you're looking up? I'm not even sure how to say that clearly in English, which is probably the root of my problem with not being able to get it into code. For instance, today vs. yesterday OR March 28th vs. March 27th OR March 31st vs March 30th, etc. I need to find the first record based on date and then find the last record from the day prior.**

It should be something similar to this `before_save` callback:

```
def calculate_case_growth_rate
  current_cases  = self.cases
  previous_cases = Update.where(date: 1.day.ago).sum(:cases)
  self.case_growth_rate = (current_cases - previous_cases) / current_cases
end
```

Here's [the model](https://github.com/leemcalilly/coronavirus/blob/master/app/models/update.rb) where that callback happens.

But, **that approach won't work** because there are times where the data might be incorrect for a previous date and it will need to get updated. For instance, the Tennessee health department might discover they had erroneous data for March 31st, so the Johns Hopkins data gets updated and thus the record in my database would need to be updated. So with my code above, the first time that happens it would call `Update.last` and save an incorrect growth rate for March 31st. Thus, I need the callback to work whether it's calculating the growth rate for today vs. yesterday or March 28th vs. March 27th, etc.

It's an open project, so the entire app is [here](https://github.com/leemcalilly/coronavirus). (Please send a pull request if you'd like to help directly!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i have understood is that you need previous day cases. So let's say if today is April 2nd so you need April 1st case then calculate the growth rate. To get the cases from previous day what you can do is to do something like this.
`Update.where(date: 1.day.ago)` this will return cases from the previous day.
I have looked up the `date` attribute from your schema. Hope it helps

**UPDATE**: So the requirement was to fetch cases from the previous date relative to any current date and then calculate the growth rate of cases which is calculated by

```
    before_save :calculate_case_growth_rate

    def calculate_case_growth_rate
      current_cases  = self.cases
      previous_cases = Update.where(date: (self.date - 1.day)).sum(:cases)
      self.case_growth_rate = ((current_cases - previous_cases) / current_cases)
    end
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I guess because rails is already pulling the appropriate record out of the database to edit, then all you need to know is the record 1.day.ago relative to self. How do you pull the correct attribute out for that record after finding it using .where(1.day.ago)? In the console Update.where(date: 1.day.ago) returns the correct record, but Update.where(date: 1.day.ago).cases should return an integer, but it's returning an undefined method `cases' error. Something like Update.last.cases returns the integer with the number of cases. Shouldn't that pattern work with .where?

Comment: ended up with this `cases_yesterday = Update.where(date: 1.day.ago).pluck(:cases).join.to_i` but that is just pulling it relative to today's date. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yeah 1.day.ago is definitely working with 1 day from today's date. Not the record in question. What if March 28th and 29th were edited? How do I grab March 28th's cases as an integer from the database when updating March 29th?

Comment: Update.where(date: 1.day.ago) return an array which can contain 0 or more records. Calling Update.where(date: 1.day.ago).cases on on an array won't work. To call .cases there should be one activerecord object since it is an attribute of the object

Comment: If there are multiple updates for let's say 28th March so what you can do is to sum them `Update.where(data: yourDate).sum(:cases)` This will also work when there is one case since sum of array with one number would be the same number.

Comment: Really appreciate our help! The problem is not what to do with date: 1.day.ago, it's that 1.day.ago is relative to Today, not the date of the update. There could be a chance where an old Update is revised, so it would need to recalculate the growth rate relative to that date, not Today. Still can't figure out how to query this correctly with active record. You're right, this works `Update.where(date: 1.day.ago).sum(:cases)`, but how do I replace that `1.day.ago` to make it relative to the date attribute, and not Today? That's the core problem in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210880/discussion-between-maueez-ahmed-and-lee-mcalilly).

Comment: FYI, we ended up getting this question resolved in this commit - https://github.com/leemcalilly/coronavirus/commit/f6f371a87fff96df8160d6ced7c4f862f0349e31